# Using the covariance reducer in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

How do you apply the covariance reducer to an array in Earth Engine? I have two lists containing values that I have sampled from an image and would like to calculate their covariance matrix. My attempt is

```
a1 = ee.Array([1,2,3,4,5]) 
a2 = ee.Array([5,4,3,2,1])
cov = ee.Array.cat([a1, a2], 1).tranpose() \
  .reduce(reducer = ee.Reducer.covariance(), axes = [0])
```

which would return

> Array.reduce: Type must be a 1D EEArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The covariance reducer works on lists of 1D Arrays. So this code should work:

```
var a1 = ee.Array([1,2,3,4,5]) 
var a2 = ee.Array([5,4,3,2,1])
var cov = ee.List([a1, a2])
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.covariance())
print(cov)
```

Comment: Thank you. How about their 2 x 2 covariance matrix?

Comment: Hi @korndog, it might be worth asking a second question for the 2 x 2 covariance matrix - it seems useful for the community and would be easier to find as a separate question (though might not be possible given the input is "some number of 1-D arrays"). Additionally, please accept this answer (click check mark below the vote tally) if it satisfies your question so that others looking can quickly identify this as a completed Q&A.

Comment: Thanks @JustinBraaten for the community tips and insight on my question. Currently settled on calculating it by definintion.